# isset works in chrome,IE 11 and edge but not in firefox and safari?

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, isset

**SAMPLE code:**

```
<html>
<?php
        if( isset($_POST['cancele']) )
        {   
            $link=true;
        }
?>

<form id="eventform" name="selection" method="post">
    <div id="starttime">
        Pick event start time<br>
        <input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdatepicker" value="<?php 
     echo $curDateDisp; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="starttimehours" id="starttimehr" maxlength="2" style="width:18px" value="<?php echo $curTimeDispHr; ?>">:
        <input type="text" name="starttimeminutes" id="starttimemin" maxlength="2" style="width:18px" value="<?php echo $curTimeDispMin; ?>">
    </div>
    <div id="stoptime">
        Pick event stop time<br>
        <input type="text" name="stopdate" id="stopdatepicker" value="<?php  echo $futureDateDisp; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="stoptimehours" id="stoptimehr" maxlength="2" style="width:18px" value="<?php echo $futureTimeDispHr; ?>">:
        <input type="text" name="stoptimeminutes" id="stoptimemin" maxlength="2" style="width:18px" value="<?php echo $futureTimeDispMin; ?>">
    </div>
    <div id="callinterval">
        Select call interval for event<br>
        <select name="eventInterval">
            <option value="300" <?php if($edit && $eventinterval==300) echo 'selected'; ?>>5 minutes</option>
            <option value="600" <?php if(!$edit || $eventinterval==600) echo 'selected'; ?>>10 minutes</option>
            <option value="900" <?php if($edit && $eventinterval==900) echo 'selected'; ?>>15 minutes</option>
            <option value="1800" <?php if($edit && $eventinterval==1800) echo 'selected'; ?>>30 minutes</option>
            <option value="3600" <?php if($edit && $eventinterval==3600) echo 'selected'; ?>>1 hour</option>
            <option value="86400" <?php if($edit && $eventinterval==86400) echo 'selected'; ?>>1 day</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <input id="scheduleokbutton" type="submit" onclick="return validateForm()" action="scheduleevent.php" value="Add Event">

    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <input id="canceleventbutton" alt="center" name="cancele" type="submit" onclick="cancelEvent()" action="scheduleevent.php" value="Cancel Event">    
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</form>
</html>
```

I'm trying to change the form data when the cancel button is pressed and i am using isset() function for it. It doesn't seem to work in firefox and safari where it works fine in chrome IE11 and edge browsers. In firefox and safari it does not enter into the isset condition for some reason. Can someone help?

Comment: @Crowder Sorry that was a typo. It's a huge code i can't get u looking at all of it now. I hope you understood the problem though.